# How to run a docker container with specific GPUs using Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker, cuda, nvidia-docker, dockerpy

In the command line I am used to run/create containers with specific GPUs using the --gpus argument:

`docker run -it --gpus '"device=0,2"' ubuntu nvidia-smi`

The Docker SDK for Python documentation was not very helpful and I could not find a good explanation on how to do the same with the python SDK. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you can run/create docker containers with specific GPUs using the Docker SDK for Python:

```
client.containers.run('ubuntu',
                          "nvidia-smi",
                           device_requests=[
                           docker.types.DeviceRequest(device_ids=["0,2"], capabilities=[['gpu']])])
```

This way you can also use other GPU resource options specified here:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/